# How do I set the project name in the Google iOS Sign-In screen?

Tags: ios, google-oauth, google-signin

I have Google sign-in working, but the OAuth screen says:

Project Default Service Account would like to:

- View your email address
- View your basic profile info

I want it to say Project  instead of Default Service Account.

Answer (score 9):

First you need to go to google console with this link https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Then in the console select your project for which you want to change the name like this

[image]

Then from the three dots in the left select Project Setting

[image]

In Project Setting change the name of your Project

[image]

This will change the display name.

**Edit**

Updated URL as per the comment of [Steven Soneff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5001016/steven-soneff)

Comment: I appreciate the pointer.  Unfortunately, it looks like I already set my project name in that field, when I set up the sign-in flow.  So it must be something else.

Comment: Try https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent instead. Can you update this answer?

Comment: This should be the answer now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854283/google-sign-in-showing-incorrect-project-name-ios