# Google sign-in showing incorrect project name - iOS

Tags: ios, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have been integrating Google sign-in for syncing the calendar events using Google Calendar API. While trying to sign in, I am getting this.

[image: Google sign in issue]

As you can see the name of the project/app is displayed as "project-xxxxxxxxx" rather than the project name itself. How can I display the original project name here?

I have already tried
[How do I set the project name in the Google iOS Sign-In screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668867/how-do-i-set-the-project-name-in-the-google-ios-sign-in-screen)
, but of no use!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668867/how-do-i-set-the-project-name-in-the-google-ios-sign-in-screen

Comment: Already tried this.. not working!! @JigarDarji

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Atlast I found it!
I am also using Firebase for database. So when I checked its console , there is an option "**Public-facing name**" and renamed it. It worked!

Steps for the solution:

1. Go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and select the project.
2. Under **Settings**, select the **General** tab.
3. Change the **Public-facing name** by clicking the Edit button and then **Save**.

Please check the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `OAUTH Client_ID` by mentioning with your project name. It will display the same name which you specify in Google auth Console.
[click here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?refresh=1) to open google auth console.

Comment: already have a Client_ID which is include in the Info plist file also. @sathish

Answer (score 0):

**Open:** Google Clound Platform /
APIs & Services / OAuth consent screen

**Edit project name**

[image]